# Labeling user-defined shapes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, scoping

I have modified code for rotating a primitive 'match' shape (adapted from rotating camera code found here ([Use a custom shape as a "building block"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65642/use-a-custom-shape-as-a-building-block/65647#65647)).

How do I pass the label parameter in the scope so each match is a different number. Now, all nodes are hardcoded to '2'

I am new to TikZ, so cannot understand exactly how to do it.

```
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}  

\def\match#1#2{    
\begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]    
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2.5,0.2);    
\draw [fill=black](2.3,0.1) ellipse (0.35 and 0.2) node at (1,0.1)
[fill=white,opacity=.2,text opacity=1,circle, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1pt]{\textbf{2}};    
\end{scope}    
}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
\match{(0,0)}{45}    
\match{(-0.3,-0.18)}{315}    
\match{(1.85,2.06)}{315}    
\match{(1.89,-1.89)}{45}    
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the node text as third argument to `\match`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\match[3]{%
    \begin{scope}[shift={#1}, rotate=#2]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2.5,0.2);
    \draw [fill=black](2.3,0.1) ellipse (0.35 and 0.2) node at (1,0.1)
        [fill=white,%
        opacity=.2,%
        text opacity=1,%
        circle,%
        inner sep=0pt,%
        minimum size=1pt]{\textbf{#3}};
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \match{(0,0)}{45}{4}
    \match{(-0.3,-0.18)}{315}{5}
    \match{(1.85,2.06)}{315}{3}
    \match{(1.89,-1.89)}{45}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Genius! I knew the third parameter had to be passed but being new to this I didn't know how.