# Advices on drawing a complex figure using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I'm working on wedding invitations and there's a logo that identifies the braid and the broom. Originally this was taken from the internet in a low resolution and quality that ruins up the overall aspect of the invitation. I'd like to draw this complex figure using Tikz, which I show below:

[image: Logo]

As you can see, the quality of the picture isn't very high and is going to look worse when it gets printed out.

There are a couple of open flanks on which I'd need some advice, to say:

**Contour of the heart:**

I'd like the heart to look just like the one located on the lower right corner of the following image: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BDWeR0RCqfU/Tec8AcrN6MI/AAAAAAAAFDw/CsikMUj4PYI/s1600/HeartCurves_801.gif
That means plotting a parametric equation. So far, I've been trying to plot the equation, but I don't find a way to plot such a function. Here is the code I've tried

```
 \documentclass[10pt,final]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=10.5cm, top=4mm, left=8mm, right=8mm, bottom=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
      \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
      \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$y$};
      \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
       \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\x,red]  plot ({2*cos(\x r)*cos(\x r)*cos(\x r)},{\x});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The question here is how to plot the parametric function.

**Branches:**

I've wondering how to produce the lines representing the branches within the heart. I was considering to produce the lines using the classical control points, but I guess there must be better ways to produce them. Also, another problem that I see is to define the branches within the contour of the heart.

**Leaves:**

For the leaves I have a simple solution that uses the control points.

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=10.5cm, top=4mm, left=8mm, right=8mm, bottom=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
\fill [green](0,0) .. controls (1,1)   and (2,0.5).. (3,0);
\fill [green] (0,0) .. controls (1,-1)  and (2,-0.5).. (3,0);
\draw [green](-0.5,0)--(0,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I could use the @Qrrbrbirlbel's answer ([Use a custom shape as a "building block"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65642/use-a-custom-shape-as-a-building-block/79653#79653)) as a base to define the leave as shapes, but the problem that arises here is to place the leaves at specific point of the branches at specific angles.

Comment: I may be wrong, but drawings such as those are tough to make with Ti*k*Z, by hand at least. There are routines to convert the images to Ti*k*Z that generate extensive code, but the final result is ok. I'm not sure how it's done you ask in [the Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), ask it or look it up I think you can get help. Though drawing it yourself will sure be a hard task!

Comment: Inkscape for example has tools for tracing bitmap images, and can export to TikZ code (might need a plugin, can't remember). (@GuilhermeZ.Santos)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I thought as much. But wasn't sure, so I let the more experienced users confirm. That's good info, thanks! :D

Comment: Related (and possibly a duplicate): [Creating logo with fancy font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145061/5764)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172336/drawing-roman-laurel-leaves-spqr-in-tikz

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**How to convert image to `tikz` using inkscape**

1. Open inkscape and import the image
2. Select the image and use `Trace Bitmap...`

[image]

3. For the image you posted I selected the following configuration:

[image]

4. The resulting vectorised version of your image:

[image]

If the lines are not smooth enough or too smooth, these parameters can be adjusted in the trace options.

> At this point I would simply save the vector image as `.pdf` and use it with `\includegraphics`.

5. To convert the image to `tikz`, there is an extension available called [svg2tikz](https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz). (Be careful, the resulting file size may be huge)

[image]

Comment: Good to know it can all be done in one application.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Also good to know that there is an alternative route, in case inkscape fails for whatever reason.

Answer (score 9):

Not a real answer - just a fake one to post this image, which was traced with potrace and polished a bit with inkscape

[image]

Dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jk4wa9vcyeklqlg/AAAhva-i-pCASvhgLoI3v8Vba?dl=0

Edit: steps of the conversion

1. Opened with Gimp, converted to grayscale, and then to black/white using the "threshold" tool
2. Converted to pbm using imagemagick's `convert` (I assume Gimp could have done that, too)
3. Traced with `potrace -s picture.pbm`
4. Opened the svg file produced by potrace with inkscape and did a bit of manual tweaking of the contours.

Comment: +1, Nice man! Would you mind giving a more detailed description on how you did the conversion? Like what options (if any) of Potrace you used and what do you mean by "polished". I'm not so used to converting graphics and its a rather useful thing to have detailed. `:D`

Comment: Apperantly there this tool [SVG2Ti*k*Z](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz) that can convert from SVG format to Ti*k*Z, that maybe helpful to the OP.

Comment: @Guilherme - see edited answer. As to converting to TikZ, I don't really see a need for that; instead, I would just save as pdf from inkscape and then use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: i don't too. It was only a suggestion. Meant for the OP. ;) thanks for the steps, that's very helpful!