# Different Style of pi infinity symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikzsymbols

Hi I am trying to create the following symbol in Latex. I am not able to make symbol of infinity to hang at the leg of pi as shown in symbol. The picture the I want is

[image]

But I got so far is the following.

[image]

The code I have so far is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{15} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}

 % \fill[blue!10!white] (-0.1,0) circle[radius=3.55mm];   

 \contourlength{0.05mm};

 \node (infinity) at (0.6mm,-0.1) {
                    \large\bf\color{blue!60!black}\contour{white}{$\infty$}};                   
 \contourlength{0.05mm};
  \node (pi) at (1mm,0) {
                    \LARGE\bf\color{blue!60!white}\contour{white}{$\pi$}};                                                                        
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Creating logo with fancy font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145061/5764)

Comment: Do you need this as a glyph or would a picture be acceptable?

Comment: The `\pi` symbol you are using does not look like the one you want : its feet do not go back up. You should first find a suitable character.

Comment: @samcarter I need this for my personal notes.

Comment: @Kumarm: ...then it's similar to the linked post as it's just like *creating [a] logo with [a] fancy font*.

Comment: @marsupilam I noticed that. I tried to find that symbol as well but couln't.  Can you please suggest me which package provide that character.

Comment: @Kumarm I am looking as well. My best finds as of yet are `\textpi` from `textgreek` and `\pi` from `upgreek`. Maybe using `fontspec` ?

Comment: @marsupilam with euler I get a different style of pi symbol which I dont like. Not luck with other suggestions. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: An idea anyway : it would be easier to do what you want if instead of using the `\infty` glyph, you drew the actual lemniscate curve by parts (the below part then the `\pi` then close the lemniscate above it.)

Comment: I voted to re-open as the main issue here is interleaving the characters which requires clipping or reconstruction of the paths before filling neither of which is addressed in the suggested duplicate. (@Werner)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yet the accepted answer uses exactly the same technique as I suggest in the linked answer - Inkscape and export... A reference has been added, so one can close it as either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

However, it relies on the use of the `mathptmx` (or equivalent) font.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine,trimclip,mathptmx}
\stackMath
\newcommand\mypi{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{%
  \stackengine{-1.97pt}{\color{cyan}\kern4.4pt\clipbox{4.4pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}
    {$\pi$}}{\scalebox{1.08}{$\scriptstyle\color{blue!80!black}\infty$}\mkern1.5mu}%
    {O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}{%
    \color{cyan}\clipbox{0pt 0pt 1.9pt 0pt}{$\pi$}\kern1.9pt}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}%
}}
\begin{document}
\[x\mypi y\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome... Thanks. Can I position this according to my needs?

Comment: @Kumarm I edited it to make it a macro, so it can be used just like any other alphabetic math character.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you can use this conversion of your image to `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{15} {
\definecolor{c8900ca}{RGB}{137,0,202}
\definecolor{c012671}{RGB}{1,38,113}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-0.10000, xscale=0.10000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
% path81
\path[fill=c8900ca,line width=0.212pt] (61.4042,151.1097) .. controls (62.9632,143.6985) and (65.4621,127.0454) .. (67.0457,113.5132) .. controls (67.5452,109.2446) and (68.0243,105.5537) .. (68.1103,105.3112) .. controls (68.2310,104.9708) and (70.8475,104.8702) .. (79.5777,104.8702) .. controls (89.4000,104.8702) and (90.9160,104.9412) .. (91.0956,105.4094) .. controls (91.2094,105.7059) and (90.4657,112.2544) .. (89.4430,119.9615) .. controls (87.7503,132.7164) and (87.5697,134.7344) .. (87.4313,142.4410) .. controls (87.2859,150.5385) and (87.0146,153.6302) .. (88.6111,158.8906) .. controls (89.7901,162.7757) and (91.6532,166.7233) .. (94.6389,169.4748) .. controls (98.0888,172.6540) and (102.5090,175.4307) .. (107.3961,175.4196) .. controls (113.1129,175.4066) and (118.2336,173.1177) .. (122.4402,169.8087) .. controls (126.3171,166.7591) and (130.7310,157.5516) .. (130.7310,157.5516) .. controls (130.7310,157.3176) and (131.0473,155.8063) .. (131.4340,154.1933) .. controls (131.8207,152.5803) and (132.1386,150.3477) .. (132.1396,149.2320) -- (132.1416,147.2036) -- (130.0487,147.2036) .. controls (127.7197,147.2036) and (127.8866,147.0128) .. (127.2043,150.4558) .. controls (126.9844,151.5654) and (126.5284,152.8141) .. (126.1910,153.2309) -- (125.5775,153.9885) -- (119.6153,156.9085) .. controls (119.6153,156.9085) and (110.6954,157.0472) .. (107.0551,154.8704) .. controls (104.8895,153.5755) and (103.1367,151.5272) .. (102.4511,148.8618) .. controls (101.8573,146.5537) and (101.8749,133.3815) .. (102.4834,124.8022) .. controls (103.1432,115.4975) and (104.2179,105.8899) .. (104.6581,105.3594) .. controls (104.9784,104.9735) and (107.5644,104.8608) .. (117.8055,104.7864) -- (130.5541,104.6938) -- (130.5541,97.4619) -- (130.5541,90.2299) -- (89.4555,90.2299) .. controls (51.3746,90.2299) and (48.1885,90.2754) .. (46.0638,90.8491) .. controls (42.9837,91.6808) and (38.5790,93.8986) .. (36.0894,95.8714) .. controls (33.6983,97.7661) and (30.3222,101.9221) .. (27.9920,105.8394) .. controls (25.9936,109.1990) and (23.7434,114.3433) .. (23.9905,114.9873) .. controls (24.1015,115.2765) and (24.7620,115.4535) .. (25.7300,115.4535) .. controls (27.2559,115.4535) and (27.3471,115.3864) .. (29.8313,112.4365) .. controls (32.7485,108.9722) and (35.0092,107.3357) .. (38.6975,106.0181) .. controls (41.0763,105.1684) and (41.8726,105.0753) .. (47.9124,104.9411) .. controls (53.4323,104.8185) and (54.5556,104.8779) .. (54.7181,105.3014) .. controls (54.8957,105.7642) and (50.8986,132.3471) .. (49.2228,141.8483) .. controls (48.4911,145.9971) and (46.9869,149.7314) .. (45.8759,150.1577) .. controls (37.8343,157.1794) and (32.1931,160.2685) .. (33.3658,167.2237) .. controls (34.2177,172.2768) and (40.8960,176.1268) .. (46.0177,175.9571) .. controls (50.9236,175.7946) and (54.9058,170.9393) .. (57.5563,166.8077) .. controls (60.4653,162.2730) and (60.7096,154.5632) .. (61.4042,151.1098) -- cycle;
% path83
\path[fill=c012671,line width=0.212pt] (39.5760,196.8912) .. controls (32.9597,195.5752) and (26.6580,190.5494) .. (23.3542,183.9540) .. controls (21.5474,180.3470) and (20.8480,177.4261) .. (20.8374,173.4438) .. controls (20.8210,167.3054) and (23.0604,162.0893) .. (27.6527,157.5688) .. controls (30.8001,154.4707) and (33.8292,152.6018) .. (37.6852,151.3788) .. controls (40.7272,150.4141) and (44.6191,150.0721) .. (44.8578,150.7486) .. controls (44.9378,150.9751) and (42.8728,153.2439) .. (40.2691,155.7904) .. controls (37.2683,158.7253) and (35.1714,161.0932) .. (34.5419,162.2579) .. controls (33.9957,163.2684) and (33.1086,164.6509) .. (32.5706,165.3300) .. controls (32.0326,166.0091) and (31.1481,167.5172) .. (30.6052,168.6813) .. controls (29.7306,170.5566) and (29.6180,171.2013) .. (29.6180,174.3336) .. controls (29.6180,177.6173) and (29.7005,178.0367) .. (30.7770,180.2231) .. controls (34.5354,187.8563) and (43.0039,191.1129) .. (52.1958,188.4596) .. controls (58.2474,186.7129) and (61.5614,184.5956) .. (68.8645,177.8102) .. controls (70.8533,175.9624) and (72.4805,174.1690) .. (72.4805,173.8250) .. controls (72.4805,173.1742) and (67.2725,168.8893) .. (61.9901,165.1939) .. controls (60.3919,164.0759) and (58.9896,163.0078) .. (58.8737,162.8203) .. controls (58.5997,162.3769) and (60.1412,155.7635) .. (60.6536,155.1845) .. controls (61.3746,154.3698) and (67.1372,158.3043) .. (74.3307,164.5227) .. controls (76.4155,166.3249) and (78.4123,167.7994) .. (78.7682,167.7994) .. controls (79.1241,167.7994) and (80.8354,166.5691) .. (82.5711,165.0654) .. controls (86.9421,161.2787) and (88.7065,159.9189) .. (88.9427,160.1551) .. controls (89.5169,160.7293) and (92.5970,166.6005) .. (92.5118,166.9585) .. controls (92.4572,167.1881) and (90.7059,168.7462) .. (88.6201,170.4209) .. controls (86.5343,172.0956) and (84.8277,173.6250) .. (84.8277,173.8195) .. controls (84.8277,174.1942) and (89.3380,178.5831) .. (92.5888,181.3716) .. controls (101.9198,189.3757) and (112.5502,191.5941) .. (120.3403,187.1628) .. controls (122.6077,185.8730) and (125.7240,182.5509) .. (126.7861,180.2914) .. controls (128.5359,176.5690) and (128.5540,172.1213) .. (126.8344,168.4630) .. controls (125.7019,166.0537) and (121.9207,162.1147) .. (119.5198,160.8432) .. controls (118.3449,160.2210) and (115.9934,159.4437) .. (114.0474,159.0344) .. controls (110.3134,158.2489) and (108.4295,157.4311) .. (106.5469,155.7781) .. controls (105.0404,154.4554) and (103.7446,152.4274) .. (103.9927,151.7807) .. controls (104.5427,150.3475) and (114.4290,149.7919) .. (118.6464,150.9573) .. controls (121.3862,151.7144) and (125.7393,153.7431) .. (127.8184,155.2319) .. controls (128.6649,155.8381) and (130.3171,157.6041) .. (131.4899,159.1563) .. controls (135.1734,164.0318) and (136.6899,168.2015) .. (136.6808,173.4298) .. controls (136.6652,182.4334) and (131.4085,190.9684) .. (123.4569,194.9007) .. controls (118.6342,197.2856) and (114.2134,197.8821) .. (108.4740,196.9224) .. controls (103.6961,196.1235) and (100.3346,194.9942) .. (95.7929,192.6620) .. controls (91.3547,190.3830) and (87.9008,187.8487) .. (82.9170,183.2143) .. controls (80.8940,181.3330) and (79.0061,179.7939) .. (78.7218,179.7939) .. controls (78.4374,179.7939) and (76.7184,181.1869) .. (74.9017,182.8895) .. controls (67.5160,189.8112) and (62.6195,192.9655) .. (55.6202,195.3104) .. controls (49.6483,197.3112) and (44.3246,197.8357) .. (39.5760,196.8912) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*(details on the conversion process can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340956/36296)*

Comment: Thank you very much. So you basically created both the symbol from scratch?

Comment: How do I position this image?

Comment: @Kumarm Depends where and how you want to position it. I just took the infrastructure from your MWE to position it.

Comment: @Werner `inkscape` -- I added a link to a step-by-step guide to my answer